# Would this proof strategy work for proving the lonely runner conjecture?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, open-problem

The problem is the lonely runner conjecture. This conjecture states that if  $k$ runners begin running down a circle of unit circumference with random speeds, it will always the case that all runners become lonely, that is, it will always be the case that each runner is separated by all other runners with at least a distance $1 / k$.

Basically, my strategy is to prove a closely related conjecture using proof by induction. This conjecture is the equal distance runner conjecture (EDRC): At some time $T_k$, for  $k$ runners with random speeds running around a circle with circumference 1, the runners all become separated by distance $1 / k$ at the same time. This implies they all become lonely at time $T_k$.

The key to proving this conjecture is to find a function $F$ that is maximized when all runners are equally far apart.  This is done with Lagrange multipliers. This function $F$ is simply the area of the polygon formed by connecting the runners together. For any $k$, $F$ reaches a maximum when $\vartheta$ = 2 $\varPi $ / $k$, where $\vartheta$ is the angle between every runner.

The induction part comes in by assuming that there exists a time $T_k$ for which $F_k$ is maximized. The base case is very easy. We then show that there exists $\varepsilon> 0$ for which $T_k + \varepsilon$ maximizes $F_{k+1}$. This means there is a future time for which all $k + 1$ runners are lonely, since they're all seperated by distance  $1 / (k +1)$.

To prove that $\varepsilon$ exists, we have to consider a fairly complicated infinite series and show that there exists values of epsilon for which the series equals zero. The infinite series is the sum of two other convergent series (this has been proven), so the sum is convergent.

Once we show that $\varepsilon > 0$ exists, this means that $T_k$ + $\varepsilon $ maximizes $F_{k + 1}$, where $F_{k + 1}$ is the area of the polygon made by $k + 1$ runners. This implies that the $k + 1$ runners are equally far apart (that is, a distance $1 /(k+1)$ apart), which implies they all become lonely at time $T_k + \varepsilon $. This implies the LRC.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570

Comment: It is exceedingly likely you have not found a proof. Don't pin your hopes on it.

Comment: Honestly, I think I may be close to it. The basic proof strategy seems to be correct and I checked it over and over again.If I can show that the value of epsilon is constant using discrete calculus, then this would imply that there is a future time T_k + epsilon for which all k + 1 runners become lonely simultaneously.

Comment: I have been "close" to solving a 150-year-old math problem for about 10 years.  Over that time span, I have not solved the problem, but I have learned a great deal of math that I never knew existed before.  Despite any discouragement along the way, keep going with this problem until you have a definite and complete solution, as the journey is rewarding in itself, sometimes far beyond any (temporary) reward for actually completing your quest...

Comment: I think this is something you should worry about after you have verified that your proof is correct.

Comment: Even if it wrong, it will at least show how not to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you are begging the question here. You are assuming that there is in fact a time where the runners are equidistant around the circle (and using that as the basis for your induction step), but that's what you need to prove in the first place!

Comment: The proposition P (k) is the statement that at time T_k, all k runners are equal distance around the circle. That is, they're seperated by a distance 1 / k, which means they become lonely at the same time T_k. P (3) is the base case. We're assuming P (k) is true and using this to show that there exists epsilon > 0 such that F_k+1 is maximized at time T_k+1

Comment: Why assume that $T_k < T_{k+n}$? In other words, isn't it possible that in the case of $k + n$ runners, they are equidistant at a time before just $k$ runners are?

Comment: But this is part of the induction hypothesis: We assume that there is a time T_k for which F_k is maximized.We can prove that P (3) is true, that is, there is a time T_3 for which F_3 is maximized. We use the induction hypothesis to prove that there exists time T_k+1 for which F_k+1 is maximized, which implies k + 1 runners become lonely at T_k+1 = T_k + epsilon.

Comment: Are you sure that there's a time for which 3 runners will be equidistant around the circle? What if the runners have irrational speeds?

Comment: There could be times T_k+1 for which all k + 1 runners become lonely at the same time, where T_k +1 < T_k. That is possible. You could consider this case, which would mean epsilon < 0. However, to show that epsilon exists, regardless if its positive or negative, you're led to basically the same infinite series.

Comment: I'll have to think about it in that case, that is, if the runners have irrational speeds. I can try to do some calculations with what I have to see if this will be a problem or not.

Comment: @DavidvonRudisil It's sufficient to prove Lonely Runner for rational/integer speeds anyway.  But it makes no sense that there is always a time at which the runners form a regular $k$-gon.  Just trying this out for a small number of runners ($>2$) should be enough to convince you: the set of points where any given pair of runners is at a fixed angle is discrete, and there are only a small number of choices for the third runner that will cause it to be equidistant at one of those very few times.

Comment: In general, if there is a moment that the runners form a regular $k$-gon and the velocity are different.then obvious they more or less should be:0,1,2,...,n. So your work is just to check the only situation...

Answer (score 11):

The equidistant runner conjecture is false for $3$ runners. For an explicit counterexample, look at a unit circle (radius $1$) with three runner speeds $1,2$, and $4$. This has the advantage of completely resetting at time $2\pi$, since then all runners are at the starting line again. It's not too hard to explicitly check this with a computer.

As is pointed out by [r.e.s.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16397/r-e-s) in a comment, we can verify this elegantly by hand as well. Nothing changes if we subtract a constant speed from each runner. So we might consider the equivalent scenario where the speeds are $0, 1$, and $3$. (The lonely runner/stander conjecture, perhaps). Then to be equidistant, the runners need to be at 1/3 and 2/3 of the way around the circle. But when the speed $1$ runner is at either $1/3$ or $2/3$ of the way around the track, the speed $3$ runner is at $0$, consoling the lazy sitter. So there is never a case when these three runners are equidistant.

Alternately, you can examine this visualization of this case (which I found on reddit's [r/lonelyrunners](https://www.reddit.com/r/lonelyrunners/)).

[image: Lonely Runners]

So no, this is not a good proof strategy for proving the lonely runner conjecture.

Comment: A computer or simulation isn't needed. Since the problem doesn't change if a fixed speed of 1 is subtracted from each of the three speeds of 1, 2, and 4, it's equivalent to having speeds of 0, 1, and 3. Now the first runner is stationary at the starting point, so equidistance occurs only if the second and third runners are respectively 1/3 and 2/3, or respectively 2/3 and 1/3, of the way around the track. But the third runner is exactly back at the start when the second runner is at 1/3 or 2/3, so equidistance cannot occur with these speeds.

Comment: (cont'd) In this version, the speeds are in units of "circumferences per unit time" (or the circle could be taken to have unit circumference).

Comment: @r.e.s. That's very elegant. I'll edit that into my answer

Comment: Maybe the equal distance runner conjecture is true only for certain runner speeds? That is, only for certain speeds $s_1$, $s_2$, ... $s_k$, we can find a time $T_k$ for which all runners are equal distance from one another and become lonely? This would imply the LRC is true for these speeds.

Comment: My strategy won't work for certain runner speeds, as you pointed out. These speeds are likely those such that $s_k$ = $n_k$ + $s_{k-1}$, where $s_1$ and $n_k$ are positive integers. But for certain speeds it will. For speeds that this strategy won't work, another strategy will have to be used to prove LRC.

Comment: @DavidvonRudisill, following r.e.s.' reasoning, we can consider the general case for three runners of speeds $0$, $a$, $b$. Then wlog the equispacing would have $at = \frac{3\alpha + 1}{3}$ and $bt = \frac{3\beta + 2}{3}$ with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$. But then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{3\alpha + 1}{3\beta + 2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, so your strategy can *at best* work for a subset of runner speeds which has measure $0$ in the space of all possible runner speeds. This is (related to) the point James Hines was trying to make with the comment on irrational speeds.