# A question about lonely runner conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, open-problem

After wikipedia:

"Consider $k$ runners on a circular track of unit length. At $t = 0$, all runners are at the same position and start to run; the runners' speeds are pairwise distinct. A runner is said to be lonely at time $t$ if he is at a distance of at least $1/k$ from every other runner at time $t$. The lonely runner conjecture states that each runner is lonely at some time."

I gave some thoughts to it by myself. Could you please tell me if my thinking, presented below, is correct?

Let's simplify the problem making following assumption:

$m_{i}$ - number of full circles which runner $i$ runs within some period of time (let's call it $\delta_{t}$), $m_{i}$ is a natural number such that $\gcd(\{m_i\})=1$, $i = 1,..,k$.

After time:
$T_{j} = \mathrm{lcm}({m_i, i=1,..,k\text{ and }i \neq j})$ all of the runners, apart from the runner $j$, cross starting point. Runner $j$ is apart from the rest (i.e. from the starting point) by some distance $d_{j}$.

It is ease to notice that $\forall j \quad \exists n \in N$: after time $nT_{j}$ we get: $d_{j} > 1/k$.

Is my thinking correct? That would be a very short proof (assuming of course boundaries put on $m_{i}$).

Comment: Compare also with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414857/would-this-proof-strategy-work-for-proving-the-lonely-runner-conjecture).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, your proof is entirely correct; however, it is not a proof of the full lonely runner conjecture, but rather a proof of a particular easy special case.

In the original statement of the problems, the speeds of the runners are allowed to be arbitrary real numbers.  It is a theorem that it is in fact enough to take the speeds of the runners to be rational.

What you have proved is that the conjecture is true if the speeds of the runners are taken to be $1/m_i$, where $m_1,\dots,m_k$ are pairwise coprime integers.  This is not enough to prove the full conjecture.

---

As an example of why your approach can't prove the full conjecture, let $v_i=i$ for $i=0,\dots,k$.  Suppose the runners have been running for time $\alpha$.    Then, by the [Dirichlet approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), there exist integers $p,q$ with $1\le q\le k$ such that
$$
|q\alpha - p|<\frac1k
$$
$q\alpha$ measures the distance along the track that runner $q$ has run.  Subtracting $p$ means subtracting off a whole number multiple of full laps, so $|q\alpha-p|$ can measure the distance between runner $q$ and runner $0$ (who is stuck at point $0$ forever).  So in this case there is always some runner within $1/k$ of runner $0$ (where there are $k+1$ runners).

In your case, however, no such bound holds.  Indeed, you have situations where all but one of the runners are clustered together at the same point but one of them is far away from the others.  So you are considering a special case that can't hope to prove other cases like the one outlined above.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of course, as you stated, it is only a special case. This simple thought crossed my mind as I was reading about lonely runner conjecture and I wanted to make sure I am correct/share it.

Comment: OK.  You're correct.

Comment: @John Gowers, Sorry because this may be a stupid question, but may you explain why $|q\alpha-p|<\frac{1}{k}$ could tell us the method of PawelB's does not make sense in general? I think this is not relevant to the situation: $v_i=i$ for $i=0,1,...,n$ . I think this situation arrive the minimum $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is just come from a explicit calculate. I need more details...

Comment: @Huxiyu PawelB proved that, in the particular case that he was studying, there is a point at which one of the runners is at a distance $>\frac{1}{k}$ from the other runners.  The example $v_i=i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,k$ shows that such a bound does not hold in the general case - every runner is always at a distance of $<\frac{1}{k}$ from some other runner.

Comment: @John Gowers. Oh I understand what is your meaning. yes this is the point.   And it is also very interesting for me to know in any moment $t$,$inf_{l\neq k,0\leq l\leq n} ||kt-lt||<\frac{1}{n}$ . And I could not prove it immediately. By the way, the situation $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n\in N^*$ and $(v_i,v_j)=1$ $\forall i,j$ is not difficult to prove , but I do not know what is the underline motive to view the original problem as an obstruction problem i.e. general strategy to prove the conjecture. could you give me some advice? Appreciate!

Comment: @Huxiyu Are you asking me for a strategy to prove the conjecture?  If I knew the answer, then it wouldn't be a conjecture!

Comment: Oh, I understand it, this is just use the dirichlet drawer principle. cut the interval $(0,1)$ into n part and there must have two members of $||kt-l_1t||,||kt-l_2t||$ distribute in one draw, this lead to a proof.

Comment: In terry tao's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02048.pdf the conjecture originated from questions in view obstruction [9] and diophantine approximation [19]. And I read the paper The lonely runner with seven runners solve the problem in dimension 7 with the view of obstruction problem. Very nearly I begin to be interesting to this conjecture and I only think in the diophantine approximation setting. I want to learn some thing about other views especially what role they play in the proof. Does these points of view crucial for the proof in known results?

Comment: I think the misunderstanding is because of the sentence "in the general case - every runner is always a distance of $<1/k$ from some other runners", because the statement of the conjecture says otherwise. I think what you meant is that in your example if we only work with *integral times* then indeed every runner is always a distance $<1/k$ from some other runners.

Comment: @quantum That's a misquotation of what I said, and not what I was getting at at all.  Note that the time $\alpha$ can be any real number, not just a rational one.  There is no contradiction with the conjecture, because the number of runners is not $k$ but $k+1$ (OP's proof was for $k$ runners, but we could easily add another runner with speed $0$ and their bound -- which this example shows does not hold in the general case -- would still hold.)

Comment: Oh, I apologize. Indeed, I misunderstood. I thought you had $k$ runners. I think there is a typo though for the range of $q$, it should be up to $k$ not $N$ (I tried to edit the post, but apparently I am unable to edit by changing only one character).

Comment: @quantum Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, that runner $i$ needs $m_i$ periods of time for *one* circle? Otherwise every runner would be at the starting point after any integral number of periods of time.

But even then, you need a stronger condition on the $m_i$'s. You need $m_i\nmid\mathrm{lcm}(\lbrace m_j~|~j\neq i\rbrace)$ for all $i$. In particular, you need $m_i>1$ for all $i$. It is for example enough if all $m_i$'s are *pairwise* coprime and $m_i>1$ for all $i$.

On the other hand, if you prove the conjecture for $k$ runners of speed $1/m_1, \dots, 1/m_k$ for positive integers $m_1,\dots, m_k$ satisfying $\mathrm{gcd}(m_1,\dots,m_k)=1$, then you have proven it in general. If in general the speeds are rationals $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(a_i, b_i)=1$, you can multiply the speeds simultaneously first with $1/\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ to get speeds $1/b’_i$ and then with $\mathrm{gcd}(b'_1,\dots,b'_k)$ to obtain the situation above.